# Can someone provide a link with an scala example of how to run Kafka-streams with inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.1-IV2?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I've inherited this code and I'm not able to understand why it doesn't work. It's supposed to work, but obviously it doesn't. It is not compiling.

I've been looking at the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/wordcount) but there are no examples in scala, just java.

My environment is osx 10.14.4, running zookeeper and kafka in local mode:

```
zkServer print-cmd
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
"java" -Dzookeeper.log.dir="." -Dzookeeper.root.logger="INFO,CONSOLE" -cp "/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../build/classes:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.13.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/libexec/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/usr/local/etc/zookeeper:"  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "/usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg" > "./zookeeper.out" 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

I am using [kafka 2.2.0](https://pastebin.com/6Pqzg9Xt)

This is what I have:

```
build.sbt

name := "Chapter3"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
"apache snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/",
"confluent.io" at "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
)

val kafka_streams_scala_version = "0.1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.lightbend" %% "kafka-streams-scala" % kafka_streams_scala_version)
```

This is the test:

```
import java.lang.Long **// UNUSED IMPORT**
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.{KGroupedStream, KStream, KTable, Materialized} **// UNUSED IMPORT, KGroupedStream and Materialized**
import org.apache.kafka.streams.{KafkaStreams, StreamsBuilder, StreamsConfig}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes
import Serdes._ **// UNUSED IMPORT**

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.util.Try // UNUSED IMPORT

case class PharmaClass(val country: String,
                   val year: String,
                   val pcnt_health_expend: String,
                   val pcnt_gdp: String,
                   val usd_capital_expend: String,
                   val flag_codes: String,
                   val total_expend: String)


object KafkaStreams {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val config: Properties = {
  val p = new Properties()
  p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-application")
  p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass)
  p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass)
  p
}

//implicit val pharmaClassSerde: Serde[PharmaClass] = new AvroSerde

val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder

val textLines: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream[String, String]("pharma")
val eachLinesAsArray : KStream[String, Array[String]]  = textLines
  .mapValues(x => x.split(","))**// missing parameter type: x** [error].mapValues(x => x.split(",")
             ^
val mapToPharmaClass: KStream[String, PharmaClass] = eachLinesAsArray.
  mapValues { x => // // missing parameter type
              ^
  {

    PharmaClass(
      country =  x(0),
      year =  x(1),
      pcnt_health_expend = x(2),
      pcnt_gdp = x(3),
      usd_capital_expend = x(4),
      flag_codes = x(5),
      total_expend = x(6)
    )
  }
  }

/*sum of expenditure on health per per country*/
**// missing parameter type on y variable**
val pcnt_health_ex : KTable[String, Double] = mapToPharmaClass.mapValues( y => (y.country,y.pcnt_health_expend.toDouble))
  .groupByKey()
  .reduce(_+_)
pcnt_health_ex.toStream.to("pcnt_health_expend")

/*sum of pcnt_gdp in year 2015 per country*/
**// missing parameter type: _**
val pcnt_gdp : KTable[String, Double] = mapToPharmaClass
  .filter((_,pharmaclass) => pharmaclass.year == 2015)
  .mapValues( y => (y.country,y.pcnt_gdp.toDouble))
  .groupByKey()
  .reduce(_+_)
pcnt_health_ex.toStream.to("pcnt_gdp")


val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config)
streams.start()

sys.ShutdownHookThread {
  streams.close(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
}
}
```

Can someone help me by giving me a hint or guiding me on how to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the outdated and deprecated library `com.lightbend:kafka-streams-scala`, instead of the official Scala API for Kafka Streams? See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#scala-dsl. The former library was contributed to and superseded by the official Scala API of Kafka Streams.

Comment: @aironman, Are you sure you are using 2.12 scala version? I think you are using 2.11, try to add `-Xexperimental` flag.

Comment: `inter.broker.protocol.version` is a broker side config and not related to Kafka Streams. Also, what does "in not working" mean? Does it compile? Does it crash? What is the error message.

Comment: Exactly, the problem was that it didn't compile due to the libraries selected in build.sbt. I thought it was clear. After changing them to non-deprecated libraries, as Noll-san suggested, the code worked. The question was if there was a GitHub repository where you could see a working example, so the answer includes just what it asked for, a GitHub repository.

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax, If you don't want to accept the answer to my question as I asked for it, there is no problem for me, the problem is already solved, but the community won't know how I solved the problem. The repository has the exact combination of dependencies needed to have a working example in scala for Kafka-streams, which is what it asked for. Confluent does not include in its official repository any example in scala, only in java and using maven.

Comment: You can find scala examples here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples